# My Package is missing modules, when importing it gives Error "No module named" pip install

Tags: python, ubuntu

I have recently moved to ubuntu, and I got some problems with installing packages written in windows.

**Solution**

I have installed package with incorrect syntax
<s>`sudo pip3 install .`</s>
I have missed **-e** flag! 
`sudo pip3 install -e .` is correct way.

If someone can describe the diffrence that would be great. Also when installing for example numpy, it does not need `-e` flag, why?

**Old**

If I will try to run it from terminal `python3 TwitterAnalyzer/_startGUI.py` or change pwd and run `python3 _startGUI.py`
it does not work. No matter if I install module in `ubuntu` or `venv`.
<s>Import in python shell works</s>. It does not work in Py Shell, I did some mistakes.

**Error:**

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'TwitterAnalyzer.GUI'`

`pip freeze` and `pip list` shows it on list. I can import whole package `import TwitterAnalyzer` but nothing from it.

```
# Project Tree
.TwitterAnalyzer
    |---LICENSE
    |---README.md
    |---setup.py
    |---TwitterAnalyzer
        |---Analyzer
            |---220_kookaburra.png
            |---Analyzer.py
            |---Readme.md
            |---secret_token.txt
            |---TwitterApi.py
            |---__init__.py
        |---GUI
            |---convertQT_to_py.py
            |---GUI.py
            |---GUI_QT.ui
            |---_App.py
        |---tweets
            |> > Ignored
        |---_collect_homeTweets.py
        |---_startGUI.py
        |---__init__.py
    |---unittest
        |---testing_GuiApp.py
    |---venv
        |> > Ignored
```

Comment: have you tried running it `python -m TwitterAnalyzer._startGUI`?

Comment: Yes, same error. I have tried also to import GUI in simple script in diffrent place, to meybe solve namespace conflict but it did not worked..
Edit:  I can import whole Package `TwitterAnalyzer` but not modules from it

Comment: I have edited question and found solution.